# Oracle SQL create variable and use output within another query

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I want to assign a specific date to a variable based on the output of a query and then use that variable in another query.  I am doing this because using sql pivot tables requires a defined element/date in order to utilize.  I can write the dates in, but i am hoping to automate this process.  Also, i would prefer not to create a temporary table or a standalone table to reference, i would like to keep this as dynamic as possible.  Can a CTE or dual table be used?  I have seen many examples, but i cannot tie all of them together to solve this issue.

Variables:

```
Variable 1: SELECT Period from Period_tbl WHERE order_id in '1'  -- 1 = current month
Variable 2: SELECT Period from Period_tbl WHERE order_id in '2'  -- 2 = previous month
```

code i want to apply this to:

```
SELECT *
From(
SELECT Period, Team, Description, dollars
from table_1)
PIVOT(
    SUM(dollars) as Period for Period in (
    to_date(variable 1, 'mm/dd/yyyy') current_mo
    ,to_date(variable 2, 'mm/dd/yyyy') prior_mo));
```

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Ok, thank you Gordon!  I am new to sql (< 2 years experience)- how do I do this?